# RegEx to find the last occurance of string in a URL

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this data

```
|-> http://www.example.com/fr/page-name (09:00:13)
|-> http://www.example.com/fr/page-name (09:00:19)  
|-> http://www.example.com/fr/page-name (09:01:41)
|-> http://www.example.com/en/page-name (09:02:29)
```

And I need to get the `(fr|en)` from the last URL in the list. In this case, `'en'`.

I'm using .Net and I've tried the negative lookaheads, which I thought was finding `en|fr` where it's not followed by `en|fr`

```
/(en|fr)/(?!/(en|fr)/)

/(en|fr)/(?!.*?/(en|fr)/)
```

but I'm missing something as it matches all URLs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you reverse the string that you are looking for and the string that you are testing and search for the first occurrence of that?

Comment: This looks like a log file; is each URL on it's own line?  Why not just take the last line and parse it out?  We may need more context for the larger problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Not sure regex is the best (or even a very good) tool for this job.

Comment: This is part of a larger single file. Each URL is on it's own line. RegEx is the only option as this file is parsed by an application that can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`[^$]+\/(en|fr)\/`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQuH4V/2)

**Explanation:**

- `[^$]+` - Matches 1+ occurrences of any character which is not `end-of-the-string`. Basically, we are just reaching the end of the whole text block using this
- `\/(en|fr)\/` - this will now match 1st occurrence of either `en` or `fr` surrounded by `/` from the end of the string(due to backtracking)

**OR, you can simply write [`\/(en|fr)(?=\/.*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/zQuH4V/4) and keep the multiline flag off.**

The required value is present in Group1 of the match.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions is great for matching String patterns, but in certain cases it can be overkill. Since you can convert the String to a URI and then get the first segment of the URI, I'd go with that route:

```
'Placeholder variable for For/Each
Dim u As Uri

'Iterate through each URL
For Each url As String In urls.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    'Split the current line by the space character, get the second item, and convert it into a URI
    u = New Uri(url.Split(" "c)(1))

    'Print the language which is the second segment of the URI
    Console.WriteLine(u.Segments(1))
Next
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YMFq2e)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I'm constrained by the application to using a Regex for this.